# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token l in JSON when converting json string to object JS

Tags: javascript, json

I am trying to achieve the following:

```
console.log(JSON.parse("{lat: 32.82619858, lng: -116.972000 },{ lat: 32.82619858, lng: -116.972000 }"));
```

however I get the following error in the console:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token l in JSON at position 3
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.<anonymous> (licence-reminderstest.php:2109)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.dispatch (jquery.min.js:2)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.v.handle (jquery.min.js:2)
```

I am wondering if anyone can spot what I am missing to convert json string to object.

Comment: Putting quotes around an object does not make is JSON. Look at what this produces: `var object = [{lat: 32.82619858, lng: -116.972000 },{ lat: 32.82619858, lng: -116.972000 }]; 
var asJson = JSON.stringify(object);
console.log(asJson);`

Comment: This error shows you JSON format is invalid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`JSON.parse` is failing because your object isn't valid JSON.

- All `JSON` keys have to be padded with `""`
- Multiple objects must be in an array

**This is what you want your `JSON` to look like.**

```json
[
    { "lat": 32.82619858, "lng": -116.972 },
    { "lat": 32.82619858, "lng": -116.972 }
]
```

**Or this as a one-line string.**

```js
'[{"lat":32.82619858,"lng":-116.972},{"lat":32.82619858,"lng":-116.972}]'
```

`JSON.parse` will recognise this as valid `JSON` even with whitespace removed.

```js
let JSONstring = '[{"lat":32.82619858,"lng":-116.972},{"lat":32.82619858,"lng":-116.972}]'

console.log(JSON.parse(JSONstring, null, 4))
```

Comment: This worked great thanks. originally I was just injecting PHP into there so wasn't spotting the sytax issues.
Thanks :)